# Call a function every time a user updates an input text field in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

My objective is to call a function whenever an user modifies in an input text field.

In my example every time the user adds or deletes a character in the text field it should call `didModify()` in synchronous thus adding 1 to `changeCounter`.

My **.html**:

```
<div class="pb-1">
  <input maxlength="10" placeholder="Text">
</div>
<p class="changedClass">{{changeCounter}}</p>
```

My **.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  text1 = '';
  changeCounter = 0;

  didModify() {
    this.changeCounter = this.changeCounter + 1;
    return this.changeCounter;
  }
}
```

[Live Demo is here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzfxua)

I saw in the past, it was $watch but I couldn't find an example in the official docs for Angular 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's bound using `[(ngModel)]`, you can use `(ngModelChange)`, like so:

```
<input maxlength="10" placeholder="Text" (ngModelChange)="didModify()" [(ngModel)]="text1">
```

This will call `didModify` each time the value changes, i.e. each keystroke

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zgbqm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 4):

Just bind to the `input` event, which fires whenever the content of the input is modified in any way (including pasting, selecting and deleting, and so on):

```
<input (input)="didModify()" ... />
```

There you are.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibuqqf